# Плеер (на сайт) для воспроизведения 3gp и mp4 на мобильных телефонах

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ли такой? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Не все телефоны поддерживают html5 или Flash так что сомневаюсь что есть смысл морочится над этим!

Comment: а что делать тада?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, нужно идти путем поддержания всех возможных вариантов. ну если это действительно нужно.

1. html5 video тэг, возможно потребуется перекодирование роликов под соответствующий формат.
2. флэш-плеер, айфон сразу отпадает, да.
3. ссылка на файл, для просмотра на внутреннем плеере телефона.

Примеры реализации каждого из пунктов ищите в сети, их полно. Тестировать все равно на конкретных девайсах надо...

В зависимости от того, что умеет или не умеет телефон, у посетителя практически наверняка получится как-нибудь увидеть видео.

Comment: ссылка на файл, для просмотра на внутреннем плеере телефона.

КАК ЭТО СДЕЛАТЬ???

Comment: <a href="file.mp4">смотреть на врнутреннем плеере телфона</a>

Comment: НАЧИНАЕТ СКАЧИВАТЬ, А НЕ ВОСПРОИЗВОДИТЬ

Comment: так и должно быть. после загрузки пользователю будет предложено открыть файл в соответствующей программе (если их несколько, то выбрать в какой).

зы capslock отожмите.

Comment: А нельзя сразу сделать, чтобы без загрузки? Точнее сразу воспроизведение чтобы было

Comment: В opere дескотопной, например, есть настройка отправлять во внешнюю программу url для конкретного скачиваемого content-type'а. Но:

1. это на десктопе
2. это пользовательская настройка
3. внутренний плеер должен уметь открывать url

тем не менее для конкретного телефона, например для андроида, не знаю, но допускаю, что есть схема url, которая позволит передать url contentResolver'у, которая сразу откроется в соответствующей программе. как это например происходит с картами гугля или ютубом... это не кроссдевайсное решение, но внимания заслуживает...

Comment: Так и не понял толком... как мне сделать, чтобы на обычных телефонах серии 40, например, видео воспроизводилось в плеере

Comment: не знаю что такое телефоны серии 40, но думаю в интернете должна быть информация по конкретному телефону и использованию его возможностей. В любом случае на каком-то этапе для конкретного девайса ваша программа упрется в невозможность управления его поведением и нужно будет полагаться что пользователь сам будет в состоянии просмотреть видео, пусть даже скаченное на телефон.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю ни флеш, ни html5 video не проигрывают 3gp, а насчет mp4 вы можете получить широкую поддержку устройств(он сам умеет переключатся на флеш, если нет поддержки html5 video) с помощью [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/). Так же можете просто конвертировать на сервере 3gp в другой поддерживаемый плеером формат.

Comment: Как на сервере конвертировать можно?

Comment: с помощью программ типа ffmpeg, mencoder, если у вас свой сервер и вы можете их поставить. Если же нет, то боюсь никак. Вот хороший туториал http://youtubeclone.wordpress.com/2007/05/26/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/